# set standard component parameter from custom lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using custom component with 'Report Summary' standard component in my community page 
custom component is a button, when click ==> it should set the value of 'recordId ' parameter of Report summary

how can i do this?

I created custom component with this code:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"  access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="Id" type="Id" default=""/>

    <table id="listTable" aura:id="listTable" class="listTable" style="" cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
        <td onclick="{!c.orgChart}" style="" class="listCell">By Organisation</td>
        </tr>

    </table>


</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    orgChart : function(component, event, helper) {
       var id='00O8E000000TKTx';
        console.log("LKLKtt");
        component.set("v.Id",id);       

        helper.chartNavigate(id,component);
    }
})
```

helper:

```
chartNavigate : function(id,component) {
        var stateObject = 'test?recordId='+id;
        var url = '/test?recordId='+id;
         history.replaceState({'test':stateObject}, "", url);

       window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = e.state.html;
        document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
    }
};
         $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    }
```

the result is : the Url in browser is updated with the new recordId but Report Summary component is not updated.
please help

Comment: Can you elaborate more, if possible a code sample would be helpful!

Comment: I edited and added code

Comment: were you able to figure this out?